# strongswan site to host example?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

There are a million site-to-site and host-to-host examples. I can't seem to find a single site-to-host example. I am looking for the most basic possible example with no certificates at all, that just listens and accepts with a simple username and password from any ipaddress, one that will work with the built-in windows client.

EDIT:
When I try the roadwarrior examples it just says my username or password is incorrect in windows

/etc/ipsec.secrets:

```
: PSK "mypassword"
```

/etc/ipsec.conf:

```
conn rw
    leftsubnet=192.168.0.0/16
    leftcert=moonCert.pem
    right=%any
    authby=psk
    auto=add
```

I get the following error

```
12[IKE] peer requested EAP, config unacceptable
12[CFG] no alternative config found
12[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
12[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
```

when I try to connect in windows and just provide the password with no username.

Any thoughts on how to correct the authentication issue?

Edit 2:

```
With the following config 
leftsubnet=x.x.0.0/16
left=x.x.x.x
right=%any
leftauth=pubkey
rightauth=eap-mschapv2
eap_identity=%identity
auto=add
```

and ipsec.secrets

```
user : EAP "password"
```

I get the following error

```
[CFG] selected peer config 'rw'
[IKE] initiating EAP_IDENTITY method (id 0x00)
[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
[IKE] no private key found for '192.168.254.137'
[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
```

Comment: You're joking, right? I mean, you really haven't found any of the many, many remote-access (roadwarrior) example configs?

Comment: ahh ok I didn't realize those were site to host, I thought those were host to host. when I try all of those windows just says my username or password is incorrect

Comment: Site-to-site fully applies to your question. No jokes.

Comment: You configured `authby=psk`. What you want instead is `rightauth=eap-mschapv2` and `leftauth=pubkey`. Windows also requires `eap_identity=%identity`.

Comment: updated config per your segestion added to edits. Looks like it made it a lot further. I am trying to avoid actually generating a key pair that I have to share with the client so this can remain simple. I don't care about security at all for this particular use case